# Changing view folder for a particular controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using netbeans as my IDE, and it runs into a world of hurt when I created a controller/views called `Tags`, presumably because it collides with some holy SVN namespace. Renaming the view folder, say, `tag_views`, fixes everything, but I would have to explicitly write out my `render` command in each action in the controller. Is there any way to re-set the view folder for a particular controller in the same way that you can set the layout for the controller `layout 'whatever'`?

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard way, would creating a symlink between tags and tag_views solve your problem?  Between you and me, I would rename the controller to something as if I had hit a reserved word and fix the path in the router.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **prepend_view_path**?

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/classes/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#M001611